# Invoke a method from a form

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to invoke a method with parameters from a form?  I know I can use an action.  I suppose closure captures variables in actions to allow this to work. Still, I feel like Methods would be cleaner.  I have a lot of these actions in our codebase and I don't like them sitting about hidden inside of methods where they are hard to refactor.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        Action action = () => form.SendToBack();//(Now Imagine this Action is 50 lines of code and there's 15 of them...Then it should make sense as to why I want to seperate this logic out into classes and methods.
        //Action action2 = AMethod(form);//doesnt work

        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {                    
                //form.Invoke(AMethod);//doesnt work see error below...also no params
                form.Show();                    
                form.Invoke(action);
                Application.Run();
            }
         );
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void AMethod(Form form)
    {
        form.SendToBack();
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I tried the overload per the comments `form.Invoke(AMethod,form);` and I get error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Delegate'

Comment: Add a button to the form and take action on the click event? (woops misunderstood the question)

Comment: There is an overload of [`Form.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx) that accepts argument parameters...

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do. You **can** just call `AMethod(form);` and this will call the form's `SendToBack` method. Also, you **can** pass arguments to `Invoke`, if you need to.

Comment: @Alex: calling AMethod(form) will not work, if form was created in another thread, which is what the code suggests. You will get CrossThreadOperation exception.

Comment: @Neolisk - Which is the point of using `Invoke` to avoid that exception.

Comment: @Ramhound: I know, just commenting Alex's suggestion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The overloads for Control.Invoke() are:

```
  public Object Invoke(Delegate method)
  public Object Invoke(Delegate method, params Object[] parameters)
```

The first argument type is the troublemaker, `Delegate` is an "untyped" delegate type.  The C# compiler insists that you use a typed delegate so that it can verify that you are invoking a method with the proper signature.  Which in your case means that you have to pass a delegate object of type `Action<Form>`.  Asking it to infer the delegate type from just the method "group" is what it won't do.  Somewhat annoying, but type safety is paramount in C#.

So the proper syntax is:

```
  form.Invoke(new Action<Form>(AMethod), form);
```

Which doesn't win any prizes.  Hard to pass up the lambda syntax that captures the form variable:

```
   form.Invoke(new Action(() => AMethod(form)));
```

An anonymous method works too, but you have to cast for the same reason:

```
   form.Invoke((Action)delegate { AMethod(form); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments from my original answer, here is a new one, that I believe OP was looking for. Thanks for help with conversion to C#.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Form form = new Form();
    Action action = New Action<Form>(AMethod);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {                    
            form.Show();                    
            form.Invoke(action, form);
            Application.Run();
        }
     );
    Console.Read();
}

public static void AMethod(Form form)
{
    form.SendToBack();
}
```