# Not block UI while loop in .Net Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, loops, asynchronous

I have a pretty heavy loop in my button click event that takes about 1-2 minutes to complete (loops around 50000 times):

```
while (continue)
{
    if (xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 == null)
        continue = false;
    else
    {
        pbar.PerformStep();
        string key = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
        Random r = new Random();
        bool ok = r.Next(100) <= 2 ? false : true;
        if (!ok)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x + 1, key);
            x++;
            groupBox2.Text = "Error (" + x + ")";
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

The loop locks the UI and it is not possible to press any button or even move the window.

[image: Can't move the window while looping]

How can I do this asynchronous or not blocking in a 'pro' way? Thanks.

Comment: Does the web service that you're calling offer asynchronous methods? If so, use `await SomeMethodAsync();`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed the problem is not in the web service call, in fact it isn't implemented yet. The loop itself takes too many time.

Comment: That's not true. A loop in and of itself doesn't take time (since it doesn't perform anything). A loop repeating 50,000 times adding two integers would take a few milliseconds, for example. So, what matter is the work that's being carried out inside the loop (and repeated by the loop). How much time it takes affects how much the loop would take to complete.

Comment: You could run the code asynchronously and wrap the update of the progress bar into a call to the `Invoke()` method, example is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955533/invoke-a-method-from-a-form.

Comment: You could put the code into a Background worker, or use a Task. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You could add your data to a DataTable instead of directly setting the value of cells. Then bind the `DataGridView.DataSource` to your DataTable. The DataTable can also be loaded using a Task. Btw, your Random is declared in the wrong place and its use is weird (just testing something?).

Comment: @Jimi That makes sense, thanks. And yes, Random is just for debugging.

Comment: You see that your UI is being blocked since you're executing code on the UI thread. I recommend using a BackgroundWorker Class so that the work can be done on a separate thread. The link that @ZedLepplin has a tutorial on it how to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the thread?

```cs
new Thread(() =>
{
    while (continue)
    {
        if (xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 == null)
            continue = false;
        else
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                pbar.PerformStep();
            }));
            string key = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
            Random r = new Random();
            bool ok = r.Next(100) <= 2 ? false : true;
            if (!ok)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x + 1, key);
                }));
                x++;
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    groupBox2.Text = "Error (" + x + ")";
                }));
            }
            i++;
        }

    }
}).Start();
```

This code blocks the exception "Cross-thread operation not valid"

```cs
Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    // Form modification code
}));
```

Comment: You need `BeginInvoke()` instead of `Invoke()`. The latter is synchronous and it has the bad habit to deadlock the UI thread.

Comment: Correct! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Application.DoEvents();` will let you work with the UI, however this might slow it down a little.